# How to query a MySQL database from embed Groovy script in a Jenkins pipeline CascadeChoiceParameter?

Tags: mysql, jenkins, jdbc, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I need to dynamically populate a parameter (CascadeChoiceParameter) with values from a MySQL database in my Jenkins pipeline. This parameter 'TYPE' is populated using its script (Groovy). I already successfully achieved this kind of database operation from within an "execute Groovy script" build step in the past, but not from a pipeline parameter in a JenkinsFile.

Strangely it seems like the JDBC driver class is not found because currently my dropdown choice shows:

```
Error: Exception thrown
java.lang.ClassNotFOundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
null
```

**JenkinsFile**

```
properties([
    parameters([
        choice(
                name: 'TYPE', 
                choices: [
                            'foo',
                            'bar'
                ],
                description: "Item type"
        ), 
        [
            $class: 'CascadeChoiceParameter', 
            choiceType: 'PT_SINGLE_SELECT',   
            name: 'ITEM_DESCRIPTION', 
            description: "Item description",
            referencedParameters: 'TYPE',
            script: 
                [
                    $class: 'GroovyScript', 
                    fallbackScript: [
                                        classpath: [], 
                                        sandbox: false, 
                                        script: 
                                            "return['An error occured']"
                    ],
                    script: [
                                        classpath: [], 
                                        sandbox: false, 
                                        script: 
                                            '''
                                                import jenkins.*
                                                import jenkins.model.* 
                                                import hudson.*
                                                import hudson.model.*
                                                import groovy.sql.Sql
                                                import groovy.sql.ResultSet.*
                                                import groovy.sql.GroovyRowResult

                                                output_list = []       
                                                db_connect_params = [
                                                                url:"jdbc:mysql://my_db_server.tld:3306/my_db?tinyInt1isBit=false",
                                                                user: "user",
                                                                password:"XXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
                                                                driver:"com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
                                                ]

                                                try {
                                                    db_connect = Sql.newInstance(db_connect_params.url, db_connect_params.user, db_connect_params.password, db_connect_params.driver)
                                                    db_query = "SELECT DISTINCT item_description FROM my_table WHERE type = ${TYPE} ORDER BY ASC"

                                                    sql.eachRow(db_query){   
                                                        row -> output_list.push(row[0])        
                                                    }
                                                    
                                                } catch(Exception e) {
                                                
                                                    msg = []
                                                    msg.push("Error: Exception thrown")
                                                    msg.push(e.toString())
                                                    msg.push(e.printStackTrace()) 
                                                    
                                                    return msg
                                                }

                                                return output_list
                                            '''
                    ]
                 ]
         ]
    ])
])

pipeline {
    agent any     

    stages {
        stage("Checking type") {

            steps {
                
                echo "Checking type : ${TYPE}"
            }
        }         
    }         
}
```

How to perform MySQL operations against the database within my 'CascadeChoiceParameter' Groovy script and make sure all needed class are properly loaded?

Comment: I tried to switch to mariadb driver, placing the driver .jar file in <JRE>/lib/ext without Jenkins restart, changing driver to "org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver" and connexion string to ""jdbc:mariadb://my_db_server.tld:3306/my_db?tinyInt1isBit=false"" in  Groovy code , but same ClassNotFoundException is thrown for "org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver"

Comment: What driver/jar version you are using for com.mysql.jdbc.Driver ? Why you are not restarting jenkins after jar placement?

Comment: @dagget: Finally I restarted jenkins service and replaced mysql references by mariadb and now jdbc driver is properly recognized